# awk - too many open files issue / date parsing

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to parse a log file that starts with a formatted date column:
`06/22/2015 00:17:59`

I'm using the following code to convert it into a unix timestamp:

`unix="date -d\""$1" "$2"\" \"+%s\""; unix | getline timestamp;`

However, when I do this, awk fails with following error:

`awk: (FILENAME=/dev/fd/63 FNR=263350) fatal: cannot open pipe 'date -d"06/22/2015 00:17:59" "+%s"' (Too many open files)`

Any way to deal with this, or to parse the date differently?

Comment: can I downvote the mark-as-duplicate? :P I would never conclude this based on that. The other question deals with files that are open, this one is about processes. Although internally awk might work in a similar way, it's not clear to users, I would never think about that. I thought when you invoked a command and piped it to getline, the process would automatically be closed once it was done.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to close your command:

```
unix="date -d\""$1" "$2"\" \"+%s\""; unix | getline timestamp; close(unix)
```

If you don't do this, a new pipe is opened for each record in your input file, which leads to the problem that you are experiencing.